String character changes (case insensitive) - Go
I saw this question on one of the socials, presented as an Apple interview question. I have had to paraphrase as it was not given in text format. (Credit: Instagram @greghogg5)

Given a string (S) which is guaranteed to contain only uppercase and lowercase alpha characters, return the number of times that the character changes, not considering case; i.e. "aAa" -> 0, "aBbA" -> 2

Here is my Go code:
strchange.go
package strchange

import (
    "bytes"
)

func CountStringChange(str string) int {
    var (
        count int
        cur   rune
    )

    arr := bytes.Runes([]byte(str))

    for i := 0; i < len(arr)-1; i++ {
        cur = arr[i]
        // Upper- and lowercase characters are 0x20 bits apart in ASCII
        if cur&^0x20 != arr[i+1]&^0x20 {
            count++
        }
    }

    return count
}

and my test cases:
strchange_test.go
package strchange

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestStrChange(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        str      string
        expected int
    }{
        {"aaa", 0},
        {"aAa", 0},
        {"aaAAbBbb", 1},
        {"abba", 2},
        {"abBa", 2},
        {"abbba", 2},
        {"abBba", 2},
        {"aBbBcCcA", 3},
        {"aAaBbBcCcAaA", 3},
    }
    for _, c := range cases {
        actual := CountStringChange(c.str)
        fmt.Printf("string: %s\t expected: %d actual: %d\n", c.str, c.expected, actual)
        if c.expected != actual {
            t.FailNow()
        }
    }
}


Are the “alpha” characters guaranteed to be ASCII, or could they be any Unicode? The latter is more and more the case for real-world inputs.

@Davislor: str consists of only upper case and lower case English letters.

cur&^0x20 works fine in ascii, but you're explicitly using rune. That makes no sense. A rune is a UTF-8 character, byte is ASCII. Are you using multi-byte characters? If so, strings.ToLower exists, why make things harder? If performance is important, you may want to skip the ToLower call, but otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it too much, eliminate the variable of upper/lower case by normalising the input

@EliasVanOotegem: The original question says "str consists of only upper case and lower case English letters.". If you don't answer the question then you get an F and we won't hire you.

Missing test cases: always test with an empty string and a single-character string.  Those are good edge cases to ensure the code is robust even for silly inputs (it does appear to be so; tests help keep it that way when you refactor).

@TobySpeight that's a very good point! I was so worried about generating test cases order of magnitudes bigger than the ones I'd written out by hand, I didn't think to cover the simple edge cases.

A few comments.
Simple is good.
strchange.go:
package strchange

// s consists of only upper case and lower case English letters.
func CountChanges(s string) int {
    c := 0
    for i := 1; i < len(s); i++ {
        // to lowercase is not equal
        if s[i]&^0x20 != s[i-1]&^0x20 {
            c++
        }
    }
    return c
}

Conforming to standards is good.
Go Wiki: Go Code Review Comments: Useful Test Failures
Benchmarks are a good check on performance.
strchange_test.go:
package strchange

import "testing"

var changeTests = []struct {
    s    string
    want int
}{
    {"aaa", 0},
    {"aAa", 0},
    {"aaAAbBbb", 1},
    {"abba", 2},
    {"abBa", 2},
    {"abbba", 2},
    {"abBba", 2},
    {"aBbBcCcA", 3},
    {"aAaBbBcCcAaA", 3},
}

func TestChanges(t *testing.T) {
    for _, tt := range changeTests {
        got := CountChanges(tt.s)
        if got != tt.want {
            t.Errorf(
                "string: %q got: %d want: %d\n",
                tt.s, got, tt.want,
            )
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkChanges(b *testing.B) {
    for range b.N {
        for _, tt := range changeTests {
            _ = CountChanges(tt.s)
        }
    }
}


$ go test strchange.go strchange_test.go -run=! -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkChanges-12    51221613   23.41 ns/op    0 B/op  0 allocs/op

Your code is less performant.
BenchmarkStrChange-12   3787999  323.8 ns/op   224 B/op  9 allocs/op


I removed the unnecessary allocations. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "Conforming to standards is good."? Could you also rerun your benchmarks, as I believe you have modified your code, and I have certainly modified mine. I am running the benchmarks locally now, and writing a test generating function so that I can test with a string with orders of magnitude more changes.

@RomeoLima: I'm no longer at the original computer. I have rerun  the benchmarks on a different computer.
